# Regex of arbitrary number of groups of digits with ';' and '\s' between groupings

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code to extract the first and last group of digits in a given string according to the cases outlined below. It works, but it does not seem optimal:

```
import re

# case 1
pattern = '\d+\ \d+'
string = 'Hello 999 888999'
test = re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)[0].split()
print('{0}, {1}'.format(test[0], test[len(test)-1]))

# case 2
pattern = '\d+\ \d+;\d+ \d+'
string = 'How are things 999 888999;222 444'
test = re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)[0].split()
print('{0}, {1}'.format(test[0], test[len(test)-1]))

# case 3
pattern = '\d+\ \d+;\d+ \d+;\d+ \d+'
string = 'It is nice 999 888999;222 444;33 55'
test = re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)[0].split()
print('{0}, {1}'.format(test[0], test[len(test)-1]))

# case 4
pattern = '\d+\ \d+;\d+ \d+;\d+ \d+;\d+ \d+'
string = 'Please help yourself 999 888999;222 444;33 55;44 6661'
test = re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)[0].split()
print('{0}, {1}'.format(test[0], test[len(test)-1]))
```

The 4 cases are:

1. Arbitrary number of words followed by digits followed by space followed by digits
2. Arbitrary number of words followed by digits followed by space followed by digits separated by ';' followed by space followed by digits
3. Arbitrary number of words followed by digits followed by space followed by digits separated by ';' followed by space followed by digits separated by ';' followed by space followed by digits
4. Etc.

Any suggestions on how to do this in one fell swoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the common pattern is you want to find the initial string of digits, and the final string of digits. You can use

```
(\d+).*?(\d+$)
```

to match and capture as many digits as soon as possible, lazy-repeat any character, until you get to another string of digits followed by the end of the string.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+).*?(\d+$)')
for str in ['Hello 999 888999', 'How are things 999 888999;222 444', 'It is nice 999 888999;222 444;33 55', 'Please help yourself 999 888999;222 444;33 55;44 6661']:
    match = re.search(pattern, str)
    print(', '.join(match.groups()))
```

https://regex101.com/r/FgVIdV/1

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('(\d+\s\d+(;)?){1,4}')

texts = ['Hello 999 888999', 'How are things 999 888999;222 444', 'It is nice 999 888999;222 444;33 55',
         'Please help yourself 999 888999;222 444;33 55;44 6661']

for text in texts:
    match = pattern.search(text)
    if match:
        split = match.group().split()
        print('{0}, {1}'.format(split[0], split[len(split) - 1]))
```

**Output**

```
999, 888999
999, 444
999, 55
999, 6661
```

**Regex**

Repeat the pattern `(\d+\s\d+(;)?){1,4}` 1, 2, 3 or 4 times. The pattern is almost the same you had:

- `\d+` One or more numbers
- followed by `\s` one space
- followed by `\d+` one or more numbers
- followed by an optional `;` (`(;)?`)

Comment: I like your solution, but the one above is more general to my case.